# How can i make shared pointer from a class object with move semantics

Tags: c++

This is my class for Mesh object

```
struct texture
{
    std::string textureName;
    unsigned int textureId;
};

class Mesh
{
public:
    /* Mesh data */
    std::vector<texture> textures;
    
    /* Functions */
    Mesh(std::vector<texture> &text);
    Mesh(const Mesh& mesh) = delete;
    Mesh& operator = (const Mesh& mesh) = delete;
    Mesh(Mesh &&other);
    Mesh& operator=(Mesh &&other);
    ~Mesh();        

};




 #include "Mesh.h"

Mesh::Mesh(std::vector<texture> &text) : textures(text)
{
}

Mesh::Mesh(Mesh &&other) : textures( other.textures)
{
    for (auto &tex : other.textures)
        tex.textureId = 0;
}

Mesh& Mesh::operator=(Mesh &&other)
{
    if (this != &other)
    {
        textures = other.textures;
    }

    for (auto &tex : other.textures)
        tex.textureId = 0;

    return *this;
}

Mesh::~Mesh()
{
    for (auto &tex : textures)
        glDeleteTextures(1, &tex.id);
}
```

Now i realize that i would need to make a shared pointer of this class object but when i try to do so it gives me error attempting to reference a deleted function , which i believe is because i am using the move semantics.

```
std::vector< texture> textures;
    Mesh m(textures);
    std::shared_ptr<Mesh> myMesh = std::make_shared<Mesh>(m);
```

Is it possible to make a shared pointer from the class object with move semantics ?

error message

Error   C2280   'Mesh::Mesh(const Mesh &)': attempting to reference a deleted function

Comment: including the error message in the question would have been nice. You already got answers, but you could still add it

Comment: @idclev463035818 Error message added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you add a move constructor then the default copy constructor is implicitly deleted and `std::make_shared<Mesh>(m)` uses the copy constructor. That's the reason why you get an error message like this:

```
error: use of deleted function 'constexpr Mesh::Mesh(const Mesh&)'
            -> decltype(::new((void*)0) _Tp(std::declval<_Args>()...))

note: 'constexpr Mesh::Mesh(const Mesh&)' is implicitly declared as deleted 
          because 'Mesh' declares a move constructor or move assignment operator
```

You need to use `std::move` if you really want to move:

```
Mesh m(textures);
std::shared_ptr<Mesh> myMesh = std::make_shared<Mesh>(std::move(m));
```

But for the shown code it is not clear why you want to do a move at all, because it seems that you don't use `m` for anything else.

Comment: i have simplified the class just to show where the problem is , this is a opengl mesh object and in the  destructor it deletes all the  texture id's.

Comment: @Summit `this is a opengl mesh object and in the destructor it deletes all the texture id's`, that sounds a bit like a conceptual misunderstanding on your side. A move constructor of `Mesh` should ensure that the `Mesh` object you move from does not manage the same objects as the one you moved to. `m` and the object managed by `myMesh` are two different instances, and for both the destructor will be called.

Comment: that is exaclty what i want  , in the treeview when somebody clicks on the object it calls the copy constructor  and passes the object forward and when the destructor for that object is called i do not want it to delete the textureId's from the graphics memory.

Answer (score 2):

`make_shared` uses the parameters to construct a `Mesh`. You either want

```
std::shared_ptr<Mesh> myMesh2 = std::make_shared<Mesh>(std::move(m));
```

or

```
std::shared_ptr<Mesh> myMesh = std::make_shared<Mesh>(textures);
```

to pick one of the two constructors that are not deleted.